# Rollbar and celery causing crash onrunning django project

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, rollbar

I'm trying to debug a problematic error which occurs when I'm trying to launch django project in which I'm using (among others) celery and rollbar. The problem occurs when I change logging level for `mail_admins` from `ERROR` to `WARNING`. Complete traceback is below:

```
(env)root@test:/var/www/papukurier_test# ./manage.py migrate
2018-01-30 13:30:52 [16517] [WARNING] pathname=/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rollbar/__init__.py lineno=292 funcname=init Rollbar already initialized. Ignoring re-init.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 120, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/courier/apps.py", line 4, in <module>
    from courier.api.consumers import INIT_COURIERS_CONSUMERS_SIGNATURE
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/courier/api/consumers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from papukurier.celery import celery_app
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/papukurier/celery.py", line 23, in <module>
    rollbar.init(**settings.ROLLBAR)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rollbar/__init__.py", line 292, in init
    log.warning('Rollbar already initialized. Ignoring re-init.')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1164, in warning
    self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1271, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1281, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1321, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 749, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 119, in emit
    message = "%s\n\n%s" % (self.format(no_exc_record), reporter.get_traceback_text())
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 334, in get_traceback_text
    return t.render(c)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 736, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 764, in date
    return formats.date_format(value, arg)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/formats.py", line 162, in date_format
    return dateformat.format(value, get_format(format or 'DATE_FORMAT', use_l10n=use_l10n))
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 371, in format
    return df.format(format_string)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 42, in format
    pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 297, in r
    return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 42, in format
    pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 119, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 89, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 345, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 321, in do_translate
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 228, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 129, in __init__
    self._add_installed_apps_translations()
  File "/var/www/papukurier_test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 171, in _add_installed_apps_translations
    "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
(env)root@test:/var/www/papukurier_test#
```

This is partial logging setup:

```
   'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins_command': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'console_command': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'plain'
        },
        'rollbar': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'rollbar.logger.RollbarHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'rollbar'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'rollbar'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'papu': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'rollbar'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'invoices.management.commands': {
            'handlers': ['console_command', 'mail_admins_command', 'rollbar'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'xhtml2pdf': {
            'handlers': ['console_command', 'mail_admins_command'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'rollbar'],
            'level': 'CRITICAL',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've gone through [this discussion](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2126) but none of suggested solutions worked in my case. I started wondering whether there could be an issue with logging because if you look at the traceback, it turns out that the logging for rollbar reinit warning is handled not by the environment Python (that located in `env/` directory) but by system logger.

When I try to run python console I get this:

```
(env)root@test:/var/www/papukurier_test# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
```

**EDIT**
There's no `loggin` module in my env.

```
(env)root@test:/var/www/papukurier_test# ls env/lib/python2.7/ | grep logging
(env)root@test:/var/www/papukurier_test#
```

Comment: Hey there - You can get help from the Rollbar team with this issue by contacting support@rollbar.com or creating an issue in https://github.com/rollbar/pyrollbar/issues.  All Rollbar users are eligible for support, regardless of whether you're a paying customer or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try there.